# Permission problem when installing RStudio in an Ubuntu Bionic Beaver (18.04), x86_64

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

I am experiencing similar problems to user Aurele in this forum: https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-rstudio-desktop-on-my-linux-machine-permission-problem/7264. My error message:

> `~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb`
>   (Reading database ... 239410 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking rstudio (1.1.463) ...
>   dpkg: error processing archive rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb (--install):
>    unable to open '/usr/lib/rstudio/www/rstudio/0E471A7ED100AFCB82EF81C71F4D11F4.cache.js.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
>   Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
>   Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
>   Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
>   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
>   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb

I tried installing other older versions of rstudio (rstudio-1.0.153-amd64.deb, rstudio-0.99.903-i386.deb)

> `~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi rstudio-1.0.153-amd64.deb`
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Reading state information... Done
>   RStudio
>    RStudio is a set of integrated tools designed to help you be more productive with R. It includes a console, syntax-highlighting editor that supports direct code execution, as well as tools for plotting, history, and workspace management.
>   Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
>   (Reading database ... 239410 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack rstudio-1.0.153-amd64.deb ...
>   Unpacking rstudio (1.0.153) ...
>   dpkg: error processing archive rstudio-1.0.153-amd64.deb (--install):
>    unable to open '/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/r-ldpath.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
>   Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
>   Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
>   Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
>   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
>   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    rstudio-1.0.153-amd64.deb
>
> `~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i rstudio-0.99.903-i386.deb`
>   Selecting previously unselected package rstudio:i386.
>   (Reading database ... 239410 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to unpack rstudio-0.99.903-i386.deb ...
>   Unpacking rstudio:i386 (0.99.903) ...
>   dpkg: error processing archive rstudio-0.99.903-i386.deb (--install):
>    unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/rstudio.list-new': Operation not permitted
>   Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
>   Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
>   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
>   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
>   Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    rstudio-0.99.903-i386.deb

As you can see, each error is in a different folder. I have tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoremove rstudio`, and even forced the removal of a conflicting package (rstudio:i386) and later reinstall, without success. rstudio appears as not having been installed at all.

> `sudo apt-get autoremove rstudio`
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package 'rstudio' is not installed, so not removed
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Aurele's topic was not solved in the end. Would anyone have an idea of what is happening? Thanks!

Comment: How about `sudo dpkg --purge rstudio`, `apt update`  and `apt autoremove` ?

Comment: This is what I got. 
'$ sudo dpkg --purge rstudio
[sudo] password for csarabia: 
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove rstudio which isn't installed'

Comment: After trying again, 
'~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb Selecting previously unselected package rstudio.
(Reading database ... 239528 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (1.1.463) ...
dpkg: error processing archive rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/rstudio/www/rstudio/0534BAFDC631478EE219CB32CE77A869.cache.js.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb'

Comment: Why are you using dpkg instead of gdebi-core to install rstudio? I recently installed rstudio using gdebi in ubuntu 18.04 and had no problems.

Comment: Same problem:

`:~/Downloads$ sudo gdebi rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done

RStudio
 RStudio is a set of integrated tools designed to help you be more productive with R. It includes a console, syntax-highlighting editor that supports direct code execution, as well as tools for plotting, history, and workspace management.
Do you want to install the software package? [y/N]:y
(Reading database ... 239535 files and directories currently installed.)`

Comment: `Preparing to unpack rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rstudio (1.1.463) ...
dpkg: error processing archive rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/presentation/revealjs/fonts/NewsCycle-Regular.ttf.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...`

Comment: `Errors were encountered while processing:
 rstudio-xenial-1.1.463-amd64.deb`

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with folder permissions. You might need to log in as an administrator and/or go directly to where rstudio is downloaded and click to open and allow for installation.